# Scripting in Bash at an entry level job?

Tags: bash, scripting, python

**So, my question is how important is the ability to script in Bash or Python, etc., at an entry level position as a Linux Sys Admin?**

I'm sort of hedging that I will have time to develop those skill while on the job.

**Is this an inaccurate expectation? Will I need more of this skill up front even to pass some of the certifications like Linux+/LFCS/RedHat, etc.?**

Comment: For an entry-level sysadmin, the most important qualification is to be able to search stackexchange sites...

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for the DevOps or ServerFault sites.

Comment: jasonwryan  ... noted. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started my career as a sysadmin/devops intern.  I didn't know any bash scripting before that internship.  I would say, based on my personal experience, that sysadmins and devops-type devs/admins/engineers are jacks of all trades rather than specialists, and that we're constantly learning new skills and technologies.  All of my coworkers and I pick up new technologies every few months, and there's always a bunch of new and shiny stuff presented at the yearly devops conference we attend, but personally I have little interest in putting any of that stuff on my resume.  What's far more important than any particular technology is the ability to learn quickly and independently.  Good critical thinking and debugging skills are a must-have as well.  If you're an independent problem-solver, tinkerer, DIY-type, you'll almost certainly do well in the field.

Comment: +1. agree with all that, it matches my experience too...but want to add 'be wary of the term *devops*' - in some shops, it doesn't mean 'sysadmins and programmers working together to achieve goals', it means 'we can make the junior programmer do systems stuff for free in their "spare" time'

Comment: Yes, "devops" is buzzwordy and poorly-defined.  The point I was trying to get across is that my job involves a lot of new-school, automation-heavy, infrastructure-as-code-style system administration (though I still do manage a number of systems manually, old-school style).